# How to redirect modifying headers?

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a redirection using JavaScript like *document.location="stackoverflow.com"* but modifying headers, specifically the Referer header. So, is there a way to make a redirection using Javascript modifying the Headers of the redirection?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And explicitly on the `referer` header: it can be user-disabled in some browsers. Yet, could set the `cookie` header if you are redirecting to the same domain

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. To modify headers of the response, you have to be on the server side. Javascript is on the client side.

Comment: I think OP wants to modify headers of the request generated by the redirection actually.

Comment: Still all javascript is going to to is send a request to a page on another server. The headers I believe MUST come from the server. I'd love to some some magic that does otherwise.

Comment: I want to do like matts says. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: @Leeish: There are both *request* and *response* headers.

Comment: Ahhh... i didn't even see that he was talking about the referrer. I just read headers.